# select multiple ranges of text in text box silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, textbox, richtextbox

I have a text box control and I want to select a multiple ranges of text when i click on button.
for example:
the text is :"I want to select"
and I want that the selected words will be "want" and "select".

do you have an idea of how to implement this?

thanks,pavel.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but:

```
var words = textBox1.Trim().Split(' ');
```

Then you have an array of strings of all words. . Trim() ensures that you don't have any spaces in front or after the 'sentence'.

Comment: when i say select I mean with the method "select" of text box(and then change selection color).

Comment: OK. I think you'll need a richtextbox for that.